# How change child component v-model value in parent component correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm learning Vue.js, and want to change the child component v-model bind value, then trigger its event in the parent component.

I am using the demo from element ui documentation, want to to use the tree filter component, but sometimes I need to modify the child input value directly, but I found there is something wrong with the child component event.
Everything is fine but no child component event happens, what's wrong?

This is my `child.vue` file

```js
<template>
<div>
<el-input
  placeholder="输入关键字进行过滤"
  v-model="filterText">
</el-input>

<el-tree
  class="filter-tree"
  :data="data2"
  :props="defaultProps"
  default-expand-all
  :filter-node-method="filterNode"
  ref="tree2">
</el-tree>
</div>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['value']
    watch: {
      value(val) {
        this.filterText = val; // modify filterText value
      }
      filterText(val) {
        // this will call, but not call filterNode
        this.$refs.tree2.filter(val);
      }
    },

    methods: {
      filterNode(value, data) {
        if (!value) return true;
        return data.label.indexOf(value) !== -1;
      }
    },

    data() {
      return {
        filterText: '',
        data2: [{
          id: 1,
          label: '一级 1',
          children: [{
            id: 4,
            label: '二级 1-1',
            children: [{
              id: 9,
              label: '三级 1-1-1'
            }, {
              id: 10,
              label: '三级 1-1-2'
            }]
          }]
        }, {
          id: 2,
          label: '一级 2',
          children: [{
            id: 5,
            label: '二级 2-1'
          }, {
            id: 6,
            label: '二级 2-2'
          }]
        }, {
          id: 3,
          label: '一级 3',
          children: [{
            id: 7,
            label: '二级 3-1'
          }, {
            id: 8,
            label: '二级 3-2'
          }]
        }],
        defaultProps: {
          children: 'children',
          label: 'label'
        }
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

This is the `Parent.vue` File

```js
<child v-model="sinput></child>
...

this.sinput = "1"; // change
```

Comment: this how parent and child relationship works in Vue you can use `this.$emit` from the child to tell the parent and parent can you `props` to tell the child

Comment: yes, in fact, I using v-model passing value prop to child component and change the child component filterText value, but no filter event happen, this is what i feel strange

Comment: in your parent component try `:value` instead of `v-model`

Comment: It seems no difference, each way passing value is fine, filter behavior not working

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are binding this 'sinput' on selected tree node value, then you'll need to use event 'node-click' on tree component.

For v-model on customizing component, you need 'model' option in vue.

ref: [Vue.js - Customizing Component v-model](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Customizing-Component-v-model)

here's some code, hope it would help :)

```html
<template>
 <el-tree
   ...
   @node-click="handleNodeClick"
 />
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  model: {
    prop: 'sinput',
    event: 'change'
  },
  props: {
    sinput: String
  },
  methods: {
    handleNodeClick(data) {
      if (!data.children) {
        // your code
        this.$emit('change', data.value);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just now, I found this problem may be caused by version, in latest vue and element ui it's fine